# Why is VisualStudioOnline CI Build GetSources on premise slow?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I have set up a CI Build that is also executing some tests.

In the GetSources step Clean is set to true. 
I use a git repo.

When I run the build in a hosted agent, "getSources" takes about 20 seconds. When I run the build on a on premise agent, "getSources" takes about 20 minutes!

I can see, that the on premise agent is mostly idle in terms of cpu and memory. I also verified that network speed is at around 50 MBit/s.

Why does getSources take so long?

Comment: How big is the Git repo that's being cloned?

Comment: How long does a manual git clone from VSTS take onto the on-prem build server?

Comment: The repo is about 530 MB and a clone to an on premise system lasts around 7 mins.

Comment: Could you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug to true and queue build)

Answer (score 2):

**The Clean option has no effect for Hosted agent.**

No matter what you set for the clean option (false or true for clean sources/all build directories/output directory etc), when you queue build with Hosted agent, it always download the sources only.

Assume if you set Clean as true and clean all build directories. For private agent, it will delete the entire working folder that contains the sources folder, binaries folder, artifact folder, and so on. But for Hosted agent, it only download the sources each time.

So the execute time for Hosted agent is different from private agent for most time.

**To speed up private agent to build**, you can follow any of below aspect:

- set Clean as false (more efficient).

  Since you are queuing CI build, if you set Clean as false, the private agent will only update the files which has been modified/created/deleted to your local source folder.
- Only clean sources if you still need to set Clean as true.

  It will only clean up the files and subfolders source folder (`s/`). But if your project is large enough, you'd better use the way to set Clean as false.

Comment: How many minutes does the private agent take in Get Source step if you change the **Clean sources** only? And if it still has bigger differences between hosted agent, can you show the log separately?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "why?", it's the fact that you're copying all those files between your system and Microsoft's data center. I've experienced the same and bought some additional pipelines to accommodate.